# JavaScript delete a div (removeChild)

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

First of all I'm creating some divs dynamically (an event handler for some button) in a JavaScript function, I'm adding a button inside each div:

```
newdiv.id = counter;
newdiv.innerHTML = "Product " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'><button onclick=\"return false;
document.getElementById('"+counter+"').parentNode.removeChild('"+counter+"');\">Delete item</button>";
```

that suppose to delete that div when the button is clicked.

It's not working for me. Would appreciate some help.

Comment: Think about what "return" does.

Comment: Well there's a form on my page that I don't want to post when that button is clicked!

Comment: Further: put `return false;` at the *end*. Also, the `+counter+` string is the `id` of an element? That's going to play heck with your eyes, if you ever need to use string-concatenation with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the wrong order of the statements, the `removeChild` call is incorrect. You have to pass a DOM element to `removeChild`, not an ID.

While you could generate all the elements with an HTML string, I find creating DOM elements directly a cleaner approach when dealing with event handlers:

```
newdiv.id = counter;
newdiv.innerHTML = "Product " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";

var button = document.createElement('button');
button.type = 'button'; // see RobG's answer
button.innerHTML = 'Delete item';
button.onclick = function() {
    this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
};

newdiv.appendChild(button);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your onclick event returns before doing the `removeChild()` call

If you write it in a clearer way you get:

```
function () {
  // leave the function
  return false; 
  // never executed, because you called return right before
  document.getElementById(counter).parentNode.removeChild(counter);
}
```

You have to return **after** you've done whatever you want. Move the `return false;` to the end of the event.

Comment: When I put the return after calling removeChild it submits my form (which shouldn't)

Comment: Aside from that, `removeChild` expects a DOM element, not an ID (or whatever `counter` is). @Damarawy: That happens probably because the whole `removeChild` line throws an error. [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Comment: @Damarawy: check your browser's console log, you probably have an error in your removeChild() code. Your single quotes around counter seem pretty wrong and should throw errors.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks I think I was actually passing an ID to 'removeChild' insted of DOM element..can you put it as an answer so that I vote for it?

Answer (score 1):

`return` ends the execution of the javascript.  Nothing after the return statement is going to execute.

Answer (score 1):

By default, a button in a form is type submit. To stop it submitting the form, make it `type="button"`. Then you don't need `return false`, which, if it was needed, should be at the end of the function.

An alternative is to use an input type button. It looks exactly like a button and also will not submit the form.

It would be far better to use DOM methods to add the extra elements and the listener, but here's an innerHTML version that is a bit easier to read (to me at least):

```
newdiv.innerHTML = 'Product ' + (counter + 1) + '<br><input type="text" name="myInputs[]">' + 
                   '<button type="button" onclick="var el = document.getElementById(\'' + (counter + 1) + '\');' +
                   'el.parentNode.removeChild(el);">Delete item</button>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're returning false before your code gets a chance to execute (try putting it after the document.getElementById statement chain). Also, I wouldn't begin any HTML attribute with a plus symbol.